# Optimized replacement for "VTRN" instruction in AArch64

Tags: c, assembly, arm, neon, arm64

I am trying to develop a highly optimized code using advanced SIMD assembly instructions on AArch64. What I want to do is separating upper half and lower half of two 64-bit elements into two vector registers as it is illustrated in following picture:
[image]

In AArch32 NEON instruction set, we can do this simply by one `vtrn.32` instruction as:
`"vtrn.32 q0, q1 \n\t"`, however after trying almost all the combinations of `trn1` and `trn2` in AArch64, I could do this as:

```
"trn2 v1.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s \n\t"
"trn1 v0.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s \n\t" //v2 is another vector register which is set to "0"
```

In my code, I need to do this for 500 times and since it requires one extra instruction compare with AArch32 NEON, my AArch64 performance is degraded considerably. I am wondering if you guys can help me with this and suggest me any single instruction which can do this logic like AArch32.

Comment: @Olaf as I mentioned in my question, my intention is to write an extremely optimized code which outperforms my AArch32 implementation of the same algorithm. Currently due to these 500 extra instructions, my clock cycles is much more than my AArch32 implementation (around 1500-2000 CCs)

Comment: The A64 `trn1, trn2` pair should cost at _most_ 1 extra cycle - it's the exact same operation, just issued in two parts (indeed, the optimisation guides show that the A32 Q-form `vtrn` has half the throughput compared to all other transpose instructions). If you have a "considerable" performance difference it's almost certainly down to pipeline stalls from poor register allocation/instruction scheduling, which is a strong argument in favour of using intrinsics over assembly (along with the other big one of only having to write the code once).

Comment: @Notlikethat You're right. These instructions seems to take only one clock cycle as we had in AArch32. However, `vtrn` takes 2 clock cycles to produce result and 6 clock cycles to write back. So, it seems to me that this instruction is taking almost 8 clock cycles in average. Is that correct ?

Comment: Hang on, that sounds like the timing for Cortex-A9. I assumed you were comparing AArch32 vs. AArch64 code on the _same_ CPU - you're unlikely to get comparable cycle counts across different CPUs with different microarchitectures. That said, what the A9 tables say is that the operands are consumed in the 1st cycle, the result is _ready_ on the 2nd (i.e. it could be forwarded as an operand to certain subsequent instructions), but not actually written back to the destination register until the 6th cycle (because that's just how long the pipe is). In other words, a latency of 6 cycles total.

Comment: @Notlikethat It's the timing for Cortex-A9 or AArch32 in general. I know we cannot compare cycle counts across different CPUs, but I have not found any AArch64 instruction clock cycles reference neither in ARM info-center nor inside AArch64 instruction set overview. So, I have to compare `trn1` and `trn2` with their replacement in AArch32. You mentioned these instructions cost at most 1 extra cycle. Did you say that based on some references or that's just your experience with using these instructions?

Comment: Cortex-A9 is not representative of "AArch32 in general". Cortex-A9 is only representative of the particular pipeline design of Cortex-A9. I'm not certain about Cortex-A53, but [Cortex-A57](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/index.html) and [Cortex-A72](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0016a/index.html) timings are publicly available - you can see that on those, all transpose operations have a 3-cycle result latency, and they can issue two A64 `trn1`/`trn2` (or A32 D-form `vtrn`) instructions in the same cycle, as opposed to only one A32 Q-form `vtrn`.